# Conditionally Format Non-Blank Cell in Range When Adjacent Cell on Same Row Contains Particular Value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditionally format the non-blank cell within a range when an adjacent cell on the same row contains a particular alpha value (ach in this instance, regardless whether ACH is written in upper case, lower case or a mix of upper/lower case).

So far I've tried to apply the following custom formulas to the range `A2:C11`:

`=COUNTIF($D2,"ach")`

`=$D2="ach"`

Both formulas highlight the blank cells in the row as well as the cell populated with a value.

I've included a simplified example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fkHsUEYO5NBgApGYZs7o7L3hPdHWIlcY3FVlRXibUZ4/edit#gid=0); the result I'm actually hoping for is depicted in the image below.

[image: conditional format range]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the formulas that you tried use:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),LOWER($D2)="ach")
```

- `LOWER` will change the value to lower case
- `ISBLANK` returns `TRUE` if the current cell is blank
- `NOT` converts a `TRUE` value to `FALSE` and viceversa
- `AND` returNs `TRUE` when all the parameters are `TRUE` otherwise returns `FALSE`

Comment: This works beautifully; thank you Rubén.