# Conditionally Format Non-Blank Cell in Range When Adjacent Cell on Same Row Contains Either or Both of Two Specific Values

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Building on a question I asked [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/154631/conditionally-format-non-blank-cell-in-range-when-adjacent-cell-on-same-row-cont), I am trying to conditionally format the non-blank cell within a range when an adjacent cell on the same row contains either or both of two specific values ("ach" and/or "wire").

So far I've tried to apply the following custom formulas to the range `A2:C11`:

`=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ach",$D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("wire",$D2)))`

The above formula highlights the entire row from columns `A:C` if the cell on the same row in column `D` contains either ach, wire or both of these values. This is close, but I need only the non-blank cell on the row to be highlighted.

`=OR(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ach",$D2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("wire",$D2)))`

This formula does the same as the first; additionally it highlights the non-blank cells on the rows where column `D` does not contain either of the searched-for values (ach or wire).

I've included a simplified example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fkHsUEYO5NBgApGYZs7o7L3hPdHWIlcY3FVlRXibUZ4/edit#gid=625458790); the result I'm actually hoping for is depicted in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need both an `and` and an `or` to implement that logic. You can do that with this conditional formatting custom formula rule:

`=not(isblank(A2)) * ( isnumber(search("ach",$D2)) + isnumber(search("wire",$D2)) )`

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fkHsUEYO5NBgApGYZs7o7L3hPdHWIlcY3FVlRXibUZ4/edit#gid=485162736) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

Alternatively, use `regexmatch()` like this:

`=not(isblank(A2)) * regexmatch($D2, "(?i)ach|wire")`

These formulas use [Boolean arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra) but you can use `and()` instead of `*` and `or()` instead of `+` if that is your preference.

Comment: Both of your solutions work beautifully, @doubleunary. I particularly like how concise your `regexmatch()` solution is. Thank you!